# Limit of a weighted sum raised to a power

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, average

My professor in class used the below result to generalise the concept of averages-

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow0}(\sum_{j=1}^{m}w_ja_j^n)^{1/n}=\prod_{j=1}^ma_j^{w_j}$$ $$\sum_{j=1}^{m}w_j=1$$

All the constants above are strictly positive. He used the above the expression with n as the parameter and mentioned that for its different values, we'll get the different means. e.g. $n=1$ is clearly the weighted arithmetic mean, $n\rightarrow\infty$ would yield the maximum of the series $a_j$ and so on. These other results make sense, but I'm unable to wrap my head around the weighted geometric average.

Is there a way to prove this? Any directions to what this result is called or a reference paper would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you assume $\sum_{j=1}^mw_j=1$?

Comment: Yes. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{j=1}^mw_ja_j^n\xrightarrow{n\to 0}1$, hence by taking logarithms and recalling $\log(x)\sim x-1$ as $x\to 1$ we have
\begin{align}
\log\left(\sum_{j=1}^mw_ja_j^n\right)^{1/n}
&=\frac 1n\log\left(\sum_{j=1}^mw_ja_j^n\right)\\
&\sim\frac 1n\left(\sum_{j=1}^mw_ja_j^n-1\right)\\
&=\frac 1n\left(\sum_{j=1}^mw_ja_j^n-\sum_{j=1}^mw_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^mw_j\frac{a_j^n-1}n\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^mw_j\frac{e^{n\log(a_j)}-1}n\\
&\to\sum_{j=1}^mw_j\log(a_j)\\
&=\log\left(\prod_{j=1}^ma_j^{w_j}\right)
\end{align}
as $n\to 0$.